# Not able to display bottom tabs in bottom navigation

Tags: swiftui

I am following a youtube tutorial and for some reason my tabs for the bottom navigation will not appear.

here is all the code i have::

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  bottomnav
//
//  Created by juan on 1/24/24.
//

import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ViewA()
            
            ViewB()
             
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            Text("A")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("B")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

As you can see, its only a couple of lines but its not working.

this is the video i am watching::
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnNFoZ7CkP8

i get to second 42 and thats where i noticed that the bottom tabs are not displaying

this is what my app looks like::
[image: my app]

this is what it should look like::
[image]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: i needed to add :
 init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `toolbarBackground` is hidden by default from iOS 16. You can change it manually with this:

```swift
TabView {
    Group {
        ViewA()
        ...
    }
    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!

please add me in linkedin ::
https://www.linkedin.com/in/juanfcasas/